# Using async/await in MVC

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a web page with multiple tabs. One tab contains a lot of data, and for this reason I need to write an async method, because in synchronous way it takes long loading the tab.

I tried to do, but it seems that it behaves synchronous.

This is my controller method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ProductDetails(int id, string selected, string category)
{
 ..........
 ///Code
  #region Matching Vehicles tab               

  List<MatchingVehiclesVM> matchingVehicles = new List<MatchingVehiclesVM>();
  productVM.ProductMatchingVehicles = await GetMatchingVehiclesAsync(product.Id);
  #endregion 
}

public async Task<List<MatchingVehiclesVM>> GetMatchingVehiclesAsync(int id)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => GetMatchingVehicles(id));
} 

private List<MatchingVehiclesVM> GetMatchingVehicles(int id)
{
  //contains the code that returns from database the needed list
}
```

Can you advise what I had missed here to make it to work in async way? Thanks!

Comment: `but it seems that it behaves synchronous.` why do you think so?

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what asynchronous means in this context. Are you expecting one of the tabs on your page to populate after the page has been sent to the client? Because, that's not what will happen.

Comment: @DavidG - Yes, this is the way it should work.

Comment: @Orsi, asynchronous means that your thread won't be blocked until you get data. The load speed will not be increased.

Comment: Then an `async` action method is not going to help. You need to load that data with a different action that is called asynchronously via Javascript on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you know some page where I can take a look how  should I make it work?

Comment: Well that's a very different question. You really need to go and learn about that yourself. Start by Googling "AJAX" and you should be fine.

Comment: @Orsi: To put it another way, [`async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html).

Answer (score 1):

Few important points to note, changing controller to async will not reduce the operation time. Async request will take almost same time as sync request. In async flow, when request come to web server, a worker thread is taken from thread pool to process. During async operation, worker thread will be return to thread pool to process other web request. When async operation completes, thread is taken again from thread pool and request is further processed. This will improve scale of your web application, however individual request will take almost same time.

From client perspective call is still synchronous. You may use ajax to make async call from client and load other tab in background. Ajax call from client will not block your web page.

Very basic ajax example

```
    $.ajax({url: "products/productId1/details", success: function(result){
        $("#productDescription").html(result);
    }});
```

For more details information please refer
jquery ajax - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Async controller mvc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Hope this helps.